# how to function parameter take value automatically in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i have create a table

```
infobool (
   book_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   bid varchar(20),bname varchar(50)
 )
```

now i want use a function

```
dbo.book_id(@a int)
returns varchar(20)
as
begain
return 'bkid00'+convert(varchar(10),@a)
end
```

now  how this function take automatically value from book_id column

Comment: Format your SQL snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just trying to prepend a value to your book_id column?
You can achieve that without a function, try something like this:

```
SELECT 'bkid00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10, book_id), bid
FROM infobool
```